# Unable to add custom attributes to LDAP schema

Tags: linux, ldap

I read everything i could find and tried different examples but for some reason I just cant seem to add a custom attribute to my LDAP schema (I tried adding core schemas thinking maybe will help but still no joy)

This is the ldif I am using to add 2 custom attributes, wiki and jira

```
    # SCHEMA "WIKI-JIRA"
dn: cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: metaSchema
objectclass: top
cn: wiki-jira

dn: ou=attributetypes, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: attributetypes

dn: m-oid=1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1, ou=attributetypes, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: metaAttributeType
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-oid: 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
m-name: wiki

dn: m-oid=2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2, ou=attributetypes, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: metaAttributeType
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-oid: 2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2
m-name: jira

dn: ou=comparators, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: comparators

dn: ou=ditcontentrules, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: ditcontentrules

dn: ou=ditstructurerules, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: ditstructurerules

dn: ou=matchingrules, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: matchingrules

dn: ou=matchingruleuse, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: matchingruleuse

dn: ou=nameforms, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: nameforms

dn: ou=normalizers, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: normalizers

dn: ou=objectclasses, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: objectClasses

dn: ou=syntaxcheckers, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: syntaxcheckers

dn: ou=syntaxes, cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
ou: syntaxes
```

and this is the error that im getting

```
[root@ldap01 schema]# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/wiki-jira.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=wiki-jira, ou=schema"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectclass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Comment: There are different products that provide LDAP directory services, which server are you using?

Comment: @HBruijn Currently have two running one on RHEL 7 and one on Centos 6, same results on both<br/> 

`$OpenLDAP: ldapsearch 2.4.44 (Jun  6 2017 18:03:58) $
 mockbuild@x86-019.build.eng.bos.redhat.com:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/clients/tools
 (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20444)
` 
<br/> AND <br/>

`[root@ip-10-0-4-159 ~]# ldapsearch -VV
$OpenLDAP: ldapsearch 2.4.40 (Mar 22 2017 06:29:57) $
 mockbuild@c1bm.rdu2.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.40/openldap-2.4.40/build-clients/clients/tools
 (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20440) `

Comment: Assuming that means that you're using OpenLDAP as the server: from the [manual](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/schema.html) *"It is customary to **create a file** to contain definitions of your custom schema items. We recommend you create a file local.schema in /etc/openldap/schema/local.schema and then **include this file in your slapd.conf** file immediately after other schema include directives."*  AFAIK you don't load it as an LDIF in an already running server. (IIRC that was/is a limitation in openldap as in other directories you can load an ldif to extend schemas)

Comment: @HBruijn I am using newer OpenLDAP and it doesnt have the slapd.conf file anymore, all config is done thru cn=config

Comment: As you can tell it has been a while since I did any serious modifications on OPenLDAP :) - The ***cn=schema*** section in the manual mentions: 
*"Schema entries must have the `olcSchemaConfig` objectClass."* which is missing from your LDIF

Comment: Hmm maybe it is because when I export from Apache DS I have to export it   as ApacheDS files in order to get .ldif format. When I export as LDAP files I only get .schema extension. I was under an impression I can only import .ldif format. I will try to add attributes in ApacheDS to a core schema then export schema and import it that way.

Comment: Also can I just give my new attribute bogus OIDs like i did above or do they need to make sense? thank you